# Finfo class not found in PHP 7.0.1

Tags: php

I'm having a look at PHP 7 and how well it plays with my current projects. One issue I've come across is the `Finfo` (fileinfo) class cannot be found.

```
new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); // Class 'finfo' not found
```

As far as I am aware `Finfo` should be compiled automatically into PHP unless it is compiled with the flag `--disable-fileinfo`. Phpinfo makes no reference to fileinfo or the compile flag.

Has anyone else had this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) say:

> Windows users must include the bundled `php_fileinfo.dll` DLL file in
> `php.ini` to enable this extension.

So, enable it in your `php.ini` with

```
extension = php_fileinfo.dll
```